# An Optimization Problem for Exponential Polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis, roots-of-unity

Let $\omega$ be a primitive complex $n^{th}$ root of unity. I am interested in the following quantity
$$
\max_{f(n)\leq \ell \leq g(n)} \quad \min_{0<k\leq n-1} 
\left| 1+\omega^k+\omega^{2k}+\cdots+\omega^{(\ell-1)k}\right|^2,
$$
as $n$ goes to infinity. Note that the optimization simplifies to
$$
\max_{f(n)\leq \ell \leq g(n)} \quad \min_{0<k\leq n-1} 
\left| \frac{\sin (\pi \ell k/n)}{\sin (\pi k/n)}\right|^2,
$$
and for concreteness case I don't mind taking $f(n)=\log^2 n, g(n)=\sqrt{n}-$not the iterated log but square of log.

I know the minimum will in general can be very small (at least for arbitrary sums of roots of unity as in [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46068/how-small-can-a-sum-of-a-few-roots-of-unity-be?rq=1) by Terry Tao) but what if we are free to look at multiple lengths for the sum, and take consecutive powers, things must improve, but how much?

**Edit:**
The related problem
$$
\min_{0<k\leq n-1}\quad \max_{f(n)\leq \ell \leq g(n)} 
\left| \frac{\sin (\pi \ell k/n)}{\sin (\pi k/n)}\right|^2,
$$
which may be easier is also of interest.

One can take $n$ prime, if it helps.